# Stringify preprocesor using macros to create a string with spaces

Tags: string, preprocessor

I'm attempting to create a string with spaces for my GUI title with some macros, I have this resource.h:

```
#define QUOTE(s) #s
#define xstr(s) QUOTE(s)

#define PACKAGE_NAME                            "SoundTest"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION_MAYOR                   1
#define PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR                   8
#define PACKAGE_VERSION                         xstr(PACKAGE_VERSION_MAYOR.PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR)
#define PACKAGE_STRING                          xstr(PACKAGE_NAME PACKAGE_VERSION)
```

The above produce this output in my window title: **"SoundTest" "1.8"** (with quotes);
I want this output: **SoundTest 1.8** (without quotes). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PACKAGE_NAME` already has quotes in it:

```
#define PACKAGE_NAME        "SoundTest"
```

So if you stringify `PACKAGE_NAME`, you'll stringify the quotes as well, resulting in something like `"\"SoundTest\""`. (Remember that the C preprocessor just works with characters. It does not understand C datatypes.)

Fortunately, C lets you concatenate string literals just by writing them one after another, so that, for example, `"SoundTest" " " "1.8"` is a single string literal, just as though it had been written `"SoundTest 1.8"`. You can use that to your advantage here:

```
#define PACKAGE_VERSION     xstr(PACKAGE_VERSION_MAYOR.PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR)
#define PACKAGE_STRING      PACKAGE_NAME " " PACKAGE_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work, its not the neatest solution though ?

```
#define PACKAGE_NAME                            SoundTest
#define PACKAGE_VERSION_MAYOR                   1
#define PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR                   8
// not using this actually
#define PACKAGE_VERSION                         xstr(PACKAGE_VERSION_MAYOR.PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR) 
#define PACKAGE_STRING                          xstr(PACKAGE_NAME PACKAGE_VERSION_MAYOR.PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR)
```

Comment: I get this output in PACKAGE_STRING: "SoundTest" 1.10 (with quotes only in there)